# type max 10 characters from softkey virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I have a problem with setting max length of text when I'm using virtual keyboard. When I'm typing on normal keyboard maxlength of text is 10 characters (using maxlength in input field) but when I start to use virtual keyboard I can type how many characters I want. How can I type text length to max 10 characters from virtual keyboard. Please help. This is JS code for virtual keyboard. I know I need to set var in this code but I'm new in jQuery and it's hard for me.

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.softkeys = function(options) {

    var settings = $.extend({
            layout : [],
            target : '',
            rowSeperator : 'br',
            buttonWrapper : 'li'
        },  options);

    var createRow = function(obj, buttons) {
            for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
                createButton(obj, buttons[i]);

            }

            obj.append('<'+settings.rowSeperator+'>');
        },

        createButton = function(obj, button) {
            var character = '',
                type = 'letter',
                styleClass = '';

            switch(typeof button) {
                case 'array' :
            case 'object' :
                    if(typeof button[0] !== 'undefined') {
                        character += '<span>'+button[0]+'</span>';
                    }
                    if(typeof button[1] !== 'undefined') {
                        character += '<span>'+button[1]+'</span>';
                    }
                    type = 'symbol';
                    break;

                case 'string' :
                    switch(button) {
                        case 'capslock' :
                            character = '<span>caps</span>';
                            type = 'capslock';
                            break;

                        case 'shift' :
                            character = '<span>shift</span>';
                            type = 'shift';
                            break;

                        case 'return' :
                            character = '<span>return</span>';
                            type = 'return';
                            break;

                        case 'reset' :
                            character = '<span>reset</span>';
                            type = 'reset';
                            break;

                        case 'tab' :
                            character = '<span>tab</span>';
                            type = 'tab';
                            break;

                        case 'space' :
                            character = '<span>space</span>';
                            type = 'space';
                            styleClass = 'softkeys__btn--space';
                            break;

                        case 'delete' :
                            character = '<span>delete</span>';
                            type = 'delete';
                            break;

                        default :
                            character = button;
                            type = 'letter';
                            break;
                    }

                    break;
            }

            obj.append('<'+settings.buttonWrapper+' class="softkeys__btn  
'+styleClass+'" data-
type="'+type+'">'+character+'</'+settings.buttonWrapper+'>');
        },

        bindKeyPress = function(obj) {
            obj.children(settings.buttonWrapper).on('click touchstart', 
function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                var character = '',
                    type = $(this).data('type'),
                    targetValue = $(settings.target).val();

                switch(type) {
                    case 'capslock' :
                        toggleCase(obj);
                        break;

                    case 'shift' :
                        toggleCase(obj);
                        toggleAlt(obj);
                        break;

                    case 'return' :
                        character = '\n';
                        break;

                    case 'reset' :
                        targetValue = targetValue.substr(0, 
targetValue.length - targetValue.length);
                        break;

                    case 'tab' :
                        character = '\t';
                        break;

                    case 'space' :
                        character = ' ';
                        break;

                    case 'delete' :
                        targetValue = targetValue.substr(0, 
targetValue.length - 1);
                        break;

                    case 'symbol' :
                        if(obj.hasClass('softkeys--alt')) {
                            character = 
$(this).children('span').eq(1).html();
                        } else {
                            character = 
$(this).children('span').eq(0).html();
                        }
                        break;

                    case 'letter' :
                        character = $(this).html();

                        if(obj.hasClass('softkeys--caps')) {
                            character = character.toUpperCase();
                        }

                        break;
                }

                $(settings.target).focus().val(targetValue + character);


            });
        },

        toggleCase = function(obj) {
            obj.toggleClass('softkeys--caps');
        },

        toggleAlt = function(obj) {
            obj.toggleClass('softkeys--alt');
        };

    return this.each(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < settings.layout.length; i++) {
            createRow($(this), settings.layout[i]);
        }



        bindKeyPress($(this));
    });
};

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

> **maxlength**
>
> If the value of the type attribute is `text`, `email`, `search`, `password`, `tel`, or `url`, this attribute specifies the maximum number of characters (in UTF-16 code units) that the user can enter. For other control types, it is ignored. It can exceed the value of the **size** attribute. If it is not specified, the user can enter an unlimited number of characters. Specifying a negative number results in the default behavior (i.e. the user can enter an unlimited number of characters). The constraint is evaluated only when the value of the attribute has been changed.

My understanding of this attribute is that the browser will check upon `keydown` or `keypress` event if the value will match or exceed the `maxlength` and will return `false`.

Since these events are not being triggered by the virtual keyboard, I would advise mimicking this upon entering the value.

For example, something like:

```
var newValue = targetValue + character;
if(newValue.length < $(settings.target).attr("maxlength")){
  $(settings.target).focus().val(newValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I spend some time on this but i figure it out. Im not sure it is the best solution but I've just add var max length and from maxlength i subtract next character.                             
      var max = $(targetValue).attr('maxlength') || 20;
      targetValue = targetValue.substr(0, max-1);